# How to get image from another application windows toast using notification listener

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, notifications

Based on [Notification listener: Access all notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/notification-listener) I've been able to create an app that retrieves the information from notifications, but while notification has the attached bindings `notif.Notification.Visual.Bindings`, there is no way to retrieve the image when, for example, notification is an `ToastImageAndTextXX` (where XX is 01,02,03,04).

```cs
var appName = "whateverApp";

UserNotificationListener listener = UserNotificationListener.Current;

if (!ApiInformation.IsTypePresent("Windows.UI.Notifications.Management.UserNotificationListener") || await AskForNotificationAccess(listener) != UserNotificationListenerAccessStatus.Allowed)
{
    return;
}

IReadOnlyList<UserNotification> notifs = await listener.GetNotificationsAsync(NotificationKinds.Toast);

var notif = notifs.First(x => x.AppInfo.DisplayInfo.DisplayName == appName);

NotificationBinding toastBinding = notif.Notification.Visual.GetBinding(KnownNotificationBindings.ToastGeneric);

if (toastBinding != null)
{
    // HERE. I can just get the text, but not able to find a way to obtain also the image from the notification.
    // And then get the text elements from the toast binding
    IReadOnlyList<AdaptiveNotificationText> textElements = toastBinding.GetTextElements();
    // Treat the first text element as the title text
    string titleText = textElements.FirstOrDefault()?.Text;

    // We'll treat all subsequent text elements as body text,
    // joining them together via newlines.
    string bodyText = string.Join("\n", textElements.Skip(1).Select(t => t.Text));
}
```

Comment: I can reproduce the same unexpected behavior, I will confirm this with the team. Could you please tell us what your scenario is? Maybe we can solve the problem by other ways.

Comment: Given a media player notification on the following song (specifically with Amazon music) I want to take the information on song, artist, album AND album image to be displayed on rainmeter.

Comment: I'd suggest you submit feedback about this API in the Feedback Hub. You could find the Feedback Hub in the Start Menu. Please select **Developer Platform**-> **API Feedback** as the category when you submit your request. The related team will check the request. After submitting, please share the link in this comment area, I will submit it to the team.

Comment: Thanks @JunjieZhu-MSFT, sadly I'm not able to find it. Should I find it under my windows applications, visual studio... not sure which start menu you refer. Sorry!

Comment: Sorry I didn't explain clearly for you, you can refer to [Open the Start menu](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/open-the-start-menu-4ed57ad7-ed1f-3cc9-c9e4-f329822f5aeb#WindowsVersion=Windows_11).

Comment: @JunjieZhu-MSFT https://aka.ms/AAlyq3u this is the link :)